# How to draw more attention to my question

Tags: discussion

I submitted [a question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/139098/images-doesnt-display-in-multi-site-subdomain) 9 days ago.  It has had 12 views in 9 days.

How can I gain more views for my question if I don't have enough rep to post a bounty?  Thanks.

Answer (score 19):

I believe the culprit here is that the question just doesn't sound very interesting, and it's got rewrite rules which scare others off. People here answer in their spare time not as a job and pick which questions to look at on a whim.

There's also the hint it may be a server issue not a WordPress issue, but there's simply not enough information provided to diagnose that.

Once they get on to the question, there's also a general lack of relevant information, such as wether the image is there or not, is it viewable when viewed directly, what are the file permissions ( perhaps they're there but unreadable ), is the image markup pointing to the correct image? etc

Adding that information would make people who view more likely to answer, or give them what they need to devise one.

Getting up votes would also improve your views, you normally do this by improving your question. I find writing a question similar to a science experiment helps e.g.

- "this is what I tried to do"
- "this is why I'm doing it"
- "I did This"
- "I expected A"
- "I got B instead"
- "I looked at X Y Z and tried 1 2 and 3 with no luck"
- "I suspect it may be related to this/that"

I would also consider changing the title of your question to reflect the problem you're having, "Images doesn't display in multi site subdomain" says nothing about the cause of your issue, only the end result described at the most ambiguous level.

Comment: +1 (more if I could). For many questions such as the OP's, there is a "barrier to entry" for people wanting to provide help/answers, because the question isn't written with sufficient detail/information/context. Honestly, it gets tiring to make the same requests (please add code/more info/etc.), when the majority of the time, the OP was a drive-by anyway. **So, to make your question stand out**, provide as much information as you can, *especially* debugging/diagnosing efforts. Also, in cases such as the OP's, a live link demonstrating the issue is very helpful.

Comment: I have to agree, I backout at the sight of rewrites

Answer (score 17):

To be honest here, apart from the other two answers to your question, I can remember answering one of your questions on translating your theme. I really went overboard to help you, I even let you send me your theme so I could work on it and try to help you.

I still remebered you like in nagging me to help you. At the end I sorted your problem for you, and up till now, you have never ever, not even just once, said thank you, left any kind of comment or accepted my answer. This was 'n really bad experience for me. You got what you wanted, that is all that mattered to you.

I don't know how everybody else feels, but an experience with a particilar user also counts a lot. I vowed to never help anyone again once something like this happens, even if I'm the only one who knows the solution. Look, we are here in our spare time, volentarily, we not getting paid for any of this, so the only satisfaction that we get is an upvoted or accepted answer. Even just a thank you will do. There are one or two users I do my best to help, as they really appreciate it when my solution works.

Unfortunately you aren't the only one who have done this to me. I recently helped a new guy on the site with a problem. I even went so far as to help him with stuff that was out of scope of that particular question. When we were done, he totally refused to accept my answer because I did not answer his other previous posted question. Till today, he has also never upvoted or accepted my answer, not even a thank you.

So what I want to say is this, you must change your attitude towards people that do their best to help you. Treat me bad, and I won't even look at your next question.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately we are historically short on experts participating and consistently swamped with unanswered questions. So there is no way for each question gets same (and significant) slice of exposure.

The effort pays off though and there absolutely are things you can do to help it:

1. Make sure your question is best question it can be. While you have details and code the core of your question is "image displays as broken", which is very vague. Is file corrupted? Does server fail to serve it? Does it display unicorn instead? Without exact understanding of the problem it's hard for people to "feel" if it's a question relevant to their knowledge.
2. If you don't have enough reputation for a bounty — one very obvious action is to go make some reputation for a bounty. :)
3. Promote question directly to your network. Post it on twitter/facebook. Show it to your colleagues or professional acquaintances.